# How Do I insert multiple rows into a database in one query using Propel 2 ORM?

Tags: php, sql, propel

I have switched my project to Propel. I understand that some features that are unique to a specific database are not going to be implemented by Propel in order to be as platform agnostic as possible (example, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in MySQL). However, I am unable to locate any documentation in [Propel's Documentation](http://propelorm.org/documentation/) for the ability to insert multiple rows at once. Nor have I been able to find any references to it on SO or by searching.

Is this feature available in Propel 2?

I know that this sort of thing would work (adapted from the Propel Documentation):

```
use Propel\Runtime\Propel; 
$con = Propel::getWriteConnection(\Map\BookTableMap::DATABASE_NAME);
$sql = "INSERT INTO book (first_name,last_name) VALUES ('Leo', 'Tolstoy'),
    ('Jane','Austen')";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

However, is there an ORM approach that does not involve direct SQL manipulation?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Something analogously to CakePHP's `saveMany` (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) would be really useful in cases when a HTML form is submitted with multiple rows for the same table.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of propel is for you to write as little SQL as possible. So that example is way no.

I don't understand the circumstance you are in that requires all to be saved at once instead of upon creation but I'll go with it.

---

What you need to do is start with a object collection.

```
  $collection = new PropelObjectCollection();
```

Then you will create propel objects and put them inside the collection.

```
  $newBook = (new Book)->setFirstName('leo')
                       ->setLastName('Tolstoy');
```

If you have well defined arrays you can also use

```
  $newBook = (new Book)->fromArray($wellDefinedArray);
```

Once you create your objects you can save them then or you pop them into the collection:

```
  $collection->append($newBook);
```

And save the collection:

```
  $collection->save();
```

I strongly think you should save each one as you make the objects:

```
 (new Book)->setFirstName('Leo')
           ->setLastName('Tolstoy')
           ->save();
```

You could call the above in a loop or append them all to the collection in a loop.

If you have a very large data set a loop may not be the best.

```
(new PropelObjectCollection)->setModel('Book')
                            ->importFrom('JSON',$someJson)
                            ->save();
```

Take a look at the power of the PropelObjectCollection in [the dox](http://api.propelorm.org/1.6.0/PropelObjectCollection.html#method_importFrom)

I hope this gets you closer to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I believe this answer pertains more to Propel 1 than to Propel 2, as it is currently possible to use PDO transactions in Propel 2. The reason for wanting to write multiple inserts in one go is because it reduces server strain. After reading elsewhere, it sounds like ORM designers tend to argue that multiple writes usually are not a source of concern. When an application has multiple writes, however, I believe it would be valuable to have a syntax which allows for multiple row insertion, perhaps under the ***Query.php files. Good food for thought though, thanks!

Comment: This is very bad advice.  Typical performance tuning advice is to minimize the number of round trips to the database because of overhead.  Bulk inserts are a common need.  If a tool doesn't allow it, then it's a poor tool.